# Maintain DataTable & Variables throughout Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datatable

I have created the website in which i have to maintain the datatables & some variables in memory. Data/values in datatable or varibales will be different as per the logged user. how to maintain it?

Comment: About sessions - be aware that even if you run your website in multiple tabs, the session variable is reused between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save them as

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// I assumed that dt has some data

Session["dataTable"] = dt; // Saving datatable to Session
// Retrieving 
DataTable dtt = (DataTable) Session["dataTable"]; // Cast it to DataTable

int a = 43432;
Session["a"] = a;
// Retrieving 
int aa = (int) Session["a"];

// classes
  class MyClass
  {
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
  }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    obj.a = 5;
    obj.b = 20;

    Session["myclass"] = obj;  // Save the class object in Session
     // Retrieving 
      MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
       obj1 = (MyClass) Session["myclass"]; // Remember casting the object
   }
```

Comment: could I also store the value of the custom class objects in the session?

Comment: @RohitChaudhari - yes, you can store practically anything into the session object.

Comment: yes you can store any data type. Session supports object data type and all the types are derived from object data type.

Answer (score 2):

the perfect way to use the Session with datatable is....

```
  public class clsSession
    {
        public static DataTable dtEmp
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["dtEmp"] != null)
                {
                    return (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["dtEmp"];
                }
                else
                    return new DataTable();
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["dtEmpAddres"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use store the datatable as `clsSession.dtEmp = new DataTable();`

Comment: can you please explain why is the session variable name in set not same as the get??